# Show booktitle or journal in apalike citation

Tags: bibtex, citing, apa-style

Is there an option to also display the venue (booktitle or journal) alongside the name using the apalike bib style?

For instance, given the following reference:

```
@inproceedings{He2016,
    title={Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition},
    author={He, Kaiming and Zhang, Xiangyu and Ren, Shaoqing and Sun, Jian},
    booktitle={CVPR},
    pages={770--778},
    year={2016}
}
```

I would like to achieve the citation **[He et al. CVPR, 2016]** when calling \cite{He2016}.

In the case of an article, I would like to display the journal-title. Here is an example for an article reference:

```
@article{Russakovsky2015,
    title={ImageNet Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge},
    author={Russakovsky, Olga and Deng, Jia and Su, Hao and Krause, Jonathan and Satheesh, Sanjeev and Ma, Sean and Huang, Zhiheng and Karpathy, Andrej and Khosla, Aditya and Bernstein, Michael and Berg, Alexander C. and Fei-Fei, Li},
    journal={IJCV},
    volume={115},
    pages={211--252},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Springer}
}
```

The resulting reference should look like this: **[Russakovsky et al. IJCV, 2015]**.